# unsolved: change state with ant design select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

info: the api im calling has a parameter called vs_currency. by default i need ***vs_currency*** to be 'usd'. though, id love to use the select component to choose between at least two other assets ('btc' and 'eth'). i suppose im expecting the entire table to reload upon the selection

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      vs_currency: 'usd',
  }
}

handleOnChange = (value, event) => {
    this.setState({ vs_currency: value})    
    console.log(this.state.vs_currency);   
}

componentDidMount() {

  var vs_currency = this.state.vs_currency;

  axios.all([
     axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=' + vs_currency + '&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d%2C14d%2C30d%2C1y'),
     axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=' + vs_currency + '&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d%2C14d%2C30d%2C1y'),

...
}
render() {

  return (
     <Select key='1' defaultValue="usd" style={{ width: 80 }} onSelect={(value, event) => this.handleOnChange(value, event)}>
        <Option value="usd">$ USD</Option>
        <Option value="btc">Ƀ BTC</Option>
        <Option value="eth">Ξ ETH</Option>
     </Select>
```

What i currently have allows me to select the other asset in the dropdown but doesn't actually reload the table and show the updated currency :(

Comment: How are you changing the values? from axios request, if yes then I don't see axios response being used in select component.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to return the **response** you get from your API.

If you get the response you can modify your class like this :-
For Ex:-

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      Lenders: [],
      selectedLender: ""
  }
}
```

---

```
<select
 className="form-control"
 value={this.state.selectedLender}
 onChange={e =>
 this.setState({ selectedLender: e.target.value })
 }
>
  {this.state.Lenders.map(lender => (
  <option key={lender.value} value={lender.value}>
    {lender.display}
  </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

---

```
getNames = () => {
    fetch(
      `${environment.apiURL}`
    )
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        let LendersFromApi = data.map(lender => {
          return { value: lender, display: lender };
        });
        this.setState({
          Lenders: [{ value: "", display: "Select" }].concat(
            LendersFromApi
          )
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

And call this getNames() where you want like in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`